# How do I know Tor does not publish my identifiable information in to the public?

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, security

Can anyone tell me how and where can I check to make sure Tor is secured, without leak? And Tor does not publish my identifiable login information in to the public.

Comment: Your question is very broad at the moment and can be answered in different ways. So if you log in with your real name to some social network, your identity will of course leak. So could you narrow down the question?

Comment: I agree with @JensKubieziel; can you be more specific about what you're asking? Perhapse their is a specific facet of Tor's design that you'd like to know more about? As is, this question doesn't strike me as a "good fit" for this site.

Comment: Hi both, I mean does Tor can guarantee 100percent of leaking its users's identify? e.g. by using Tor to join IRC communicate with anonymous team, does people in IRC room could recognize where I'm coming from(IP address, Country etc.)?  Please let me know if you need more clarification than this.

Answer (score 0):

One generally does not login to Tor to use the Tor network. In addition the use of Tor network is free of charge. Thus, there is no money trail to the user. If you turst any particular VPN, Web proxy, etc. you may use them to connect to Tor network to increase your level of assurance. But some pieces of advise to the wise:

1. Any VPN, Web proxy, etc. you use to connect to Tor network should be free, such that there is no money trail to you.
2. You should trust the web proxy, VPN, etc. to the point you entrust your anonymity to them. For example it should be your private VPN you have built for your own use.
3. You should make sure there is no malware on any of your systems.
4. You may use Whonix or Tails and if you know how to combine them, do so.
5. Do not run the hidden service from your home or office.
6. Do not use a relay and hidden service on the same system.
7. Do not do anything that if become public, ruin your reputation beyond repair, damage you financially beyond repair or cause the lose of your freedom for long period of time.

Happy Toring!